# Twilio node.js survey app looping problem

Tags: node.js, twilio, survey

My twilio node.js survey app keeps looping on the second question during a call, and the second question input doesn't get saved in the database, any ideas why?

```
        questionResponse.type = currentQuestion.type;
        surveyResponse.responses.push(questionResponse);

        // If new responses length is the length of survey, mark as done
        if (surveyResponse.responses.length === surveyData.length) {
            surveyResponse.complete = true;
        }

        // Save response
        surveyResponse.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                reask();
            } else {
                cb.call(surveyResponse, err, surveyResponse, responseLength+1);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

Thanks

Comment: have you tried to debug and step through each step and see what parameter isn't updating and keeping it in the loop? perhaps a little more code to see the function parameters will help.

Comment: Have you tried to check what error you are getting that causes the question to be reasked?